# How to have footer at the bottom always but not set its position as fixed (because it comes it between of the actual content)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

am not able to keep footer at the bottom, I found a way online i.e to keep its css position as fixed. However, if I keep it fixed it is at bottom but over the actual content. How to solve this and have to footer at the bottom like real sites have?

If not possible with CSS then maybe bootstrap?

Comment: You can try to use "position=absolute" and "bottom=0" in your style...

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: Look at this example: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/

Comment: @Ingus You yourself posted the code from that website

Comment: Lucky me. .. Next time when you post a question. .. Post also information that could help to see the problem.

Comment: @Donada I tried this one as well but problem with this is it having extra space between the content and footer

Comment: without code is hard to see your problem

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Internet is full with things you need: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

This is what you want: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: I used the code from the same site you mentioned. When there is content on the page and user has to scroll the footer is not at the bottom it overlaps the content.

Comment: This page i for you: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/